# How can I add sized upper and lower borders to a heading with valid HTML?

Tags: html, css

I've got title like this : http://prntscr.com/ejxnsh but it is not valid with HTML standard, and I'm getting this error

> Element hr not allowed as child of element h3 in this context.

I've used this code

```
<h3 class="tips-tricks-title"><hr class="head-up">Title<hr class="head-down"></h3>
```

with CSS:

```
h3.tips-tricks-title{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

hr.head-up{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 75%;
}

hr.head-down{
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I've tried several things, but I can't do it without hr element in this headline.

Is there any way how can I do it? Thank you

Comment: `<hr/> <h3>Heading</h3><hr/>` - does this help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements of the headline to draw those lines.

```css
.tips-tricks-title {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
.tips-tricks-title:before, .tips-tricks-title:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.tips-tricks-title:before {
  top: 0; left: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.tips-tricks-title:after {
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="tips-tricks-title">Title</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simplify it?

```
.tips-tricks-title{
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

<h3 class="tips-tricks-title"> Title </h3>
```

Comment: This would result in borders of the same length, no?

Comment: Oops, sorry, my bad, your example is great

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my answer after reading propperly the quesition and visiting the link.

This is an alternative using svg so it will not work with browsers that don't support it.

background.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="100">
  <line x1="25" y1="0" x2="75" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="100" y2="30" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.tips-tricks-title{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(background.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<h3 class="tips-tricks-title">Title</h3>
```

Comment: This probably works, but adding markup for the sake of styling should be a last resort.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't undertand this comment @isherwood. The question at least seems to be about invalid HTML involving two hr tags and an h3 tag. Nothing has been added, it has just been put in a way it is not invalid and trying to achieve the same output produced by the code in the question. Perhaps the questions needs to be rephrased.

Comment: No, you didn't add anything with respect to the OP's original idea, but nonetheless HTML has been added to the document solely for styling purposes. It doesn't really matter who put it there; it's a bad idea.

Comment: I hadn't visited the link, it was me who had it wrong.